# Order mail on Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento for my e-commerce website.

I have set my e-mail ID at 
System -> Configuration -> Sales and Select the Sales Emails option.

Still I am not receiving any e-mail whenever there is new order placed on my site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: this might help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent